# Navigate thought a lots of array and update value of object with mongo query

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Hey guys I'm trying to update a value that is in an array in MongoDB, am trying to use the mongo queries but is not working, am following the next documentation from Mongo [doc](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831)

this one is the array:

```
{
    "_id" : "605e3d9b9ef219de662113d0",
    "distribution" : [ 
        {
            "floor" : 1,
            "rooms" : [ 
                {
                    "number" : 301,
                    "beds" : [ 
                        {
                            "number" : 818,
                            "status" : "Vacante Sucia"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "number" : 819,
                            "status" : "Vacante Sucia"
                        }
                    ],
                    "gender" : "M"
                }, 
                {
                    "number" : 302,
                    "beds" : [ 
                        {
                            "number" : 820,
                            "status" : "Vacante Sucia"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "number" : 821,
                            "status" : "Vacante Sucia"
                        }
                    ],
                    "gender" : "M"
                }, 
                {
                    "number" : 303,
                    "beds" : [ 
                        {
                            "number" : 822,
                            "status" : "Vacante Sucia"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "number" : 823,
                            "status" : "Vacante Sucia"
                        }
                    ],
                    "gender" : "M"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Meteorologia",
    "code" : "METEO"
}
```

this one is the query that is using in mongoDB to update the status from the bed `801`, room `301`, floor `1`:

in the arrayFilters i specified the index `0` to get the first element of the arrays

```
db.getCollection('establishments_copy').findAndModify({query: { code: "METEO"}, update: { $set: { "distribution.$[i].rooms.$[i].beds.$[i].status": "TEST"}}, arrayFilters: [{"i.rooms": 0, "i.beds": 0, "i.status": 0}]})
```

they are returning me the collection but without changes, is possible to navigate validating not for the index just with the values.

for example using the next query:

```
db.getCollection('establishments_copy').findAndModify({query: { code: 'METEO', distribution: { $elemMatch: { floor: 1, 'rooms.number': 301, 'rooms.beds.number': 818}}}, update: { $set: { '...': 'CHANGED'}}})
```

thanks!

Comment: there is no any fields from `rooms`, `beds`, `status` with 0 value in your collection, if you don't know about arrayFilters in update query please refer https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/

Comment: if you are trying to update `status` field in all sub documents then try `{ $set: { "distribution.$[].rooms.$[].beds.$[].status": "TEST" } }` there is no need of array filters condition.

Comment: this query will update all the status inside, i tried

Comment: can you explain which status are you trying to update?

Comment: I modified the question, is bed 818 from room 301, floor 1, establishment code 'METEO', the first one in this example question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create separate condition as per sub document's field name,

- `f` for `floor` field in `distribution` array
- `r` for `number` field in `rooms` array
- `b` for `number` field in `beds` array

```
db.getCollection('establishments_copy').findAndModify({
  query: { code: "METEO"}, 
  update: { 
    $set: { 
      "distribution.$[f].rooms.$[r].beds.$[b].status": "TEST"
    }
  }, 
  arrayFilters: [
    { "f.floor": 1 },
    { "r.number": 301 },
    { "b.number": 818 }
  ]
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4CcT62iP5ck)